# Construction of orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How to construct orthonormal basis for $S= \{(x, y, z)\mid x=3t,y=-2t,z=t;t \in \mathbb{R} \}$?
Can we try giving real values for $t$?  If so, the set of vectors get dependent. I think in this case the set of vectors should be linearly independent. 
Can someone please explain me how to proceed with this?

Thanks

Comment: What inner product are you using? Without that one cannot call a basis orthonormal or not.

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? $S $ would be a one dimensional vector space and hence every nontrivial normed vector would be an orthonormal basis.

Comment: This subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a line, so any basis has only one element.  If instead it were a plane, then once you have any (not necessarily orthogonal) basis, you could use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm or get clever with cross products (noting that the cross product of two vectors gives a vector orthogonal to both inputs).

Comment: I'm using dot product as the inner product here. Usually I'm taught to use Gram Schmidt process for this.

Comment: What I got was { 1/√14 (3,-2,1) }